# Embedded neo4j to elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, neo4j

How to combine embedded neo4j to elastic search in same maven project . I have searched but most information is for neo4j community server. But I want to use embedded neo4j and no relevant information or code is there.

Comment: Can you be a little more clear ? What do you mean by `embedded neo4j to elastic search` ? What have you try so far ? Are you just searching how to embed Neo4j in a java project ?

Comment: I am using embedded neo4j in my maven project and want to use elasticsearch in same project. And then using elasticsearch as datasource to connect to grafana .